# What's the best way to delete a word from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a variable `e.logable_type` and I want to take the word "Work" out of each one.

I tried `e.logable_type.delete "Work"`

But that got rid of all w, o, r, and k letters rather than the word.

Thanks!

Comment: The `sub` and `gsub` methods are good for this.

Comment: each chooses his best method and technique, it is enough to study the documentation and see other people's examples.

Comment: If you apply `gsub` to "There's no denying that work is a worker's job", you get `s = "There's no denying that  is a  er's job".`  If for some reason you don't want the extra space after 'that' and 'a' (not shown by the SO editor), do this: `s = s.split.join(' ')`.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is the best that can be done:

```
e.logable_type.gsub("Work", "")
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `"`. Reserve those for when you have interpolation to do.

Comment: @screenmutt (and whomever upvoted that comment) You can say that to the Ruby developers regarding the default inspect format of the string. Actually, from your comment, I can tell that you are at a beginner level.

Comment: Are you referring to `'string'.inspect`? Cause that does annoy me. But I've always heard if you're not doing interpolation, use single-quotes.

Comment: Another good reason to use single quotes is that there's no need to escape double quotes inside of them. This is useful when working with Rails, where you may find yourself setting html attributes with ruby strings, e.g. `html = 'data-id="p1"'.html_safe`. But that goes both ways: single quotes are generally preferred in SQL, so if you're packaging a query as a string, you're best off wrapping it in double quotes, e.g. `subq = "WHERE city LIKE '%land'"`, so I wouldn't categorically say you should use one or the other. Use what's most efficient given the context (in this case, single-quotes :-)

Comment: If you specifically want to delete only the word 'work', using word boundaries `\b` as mentioned in one of the answers is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'work work and do not work with me'.gsub 'work', ''
```

Comment: That does not make sense. It does not affect any variable, nor does it (always) return the modified string.

Comment: @sawa, yes(nil), edited. And I showed method usage that you can apply easily to the question.

Comment: To those who did not see the version of this answer before the edit:  The answer said: `'work work and do not work with me'.gsub! 'work', ''`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are lots of ways to do this, but here are two more. These ones won't remove partial words:

**Method 1**

```
'The Workers Work At Their Work'.gsub /\bWork\b/, ''

=> "The Workers  At Their "
```

**Method 2**

```
('The Workers Work At Their Work'.split - ['Work']).join ' '

=> "The Workers At Their"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't we use something like this which would avoid removing the word "worker".

```
irb(main):003:0> "thisis worker time".gsub(" work ","")
=> "thisis worker time"
```

instead of...

```
irb(main):002:0> "thisis worker time".gsub("work","")
=> "thisis er time"
```